# Imagej Macro Error: statement can not start with {

Tags: macros, imagej

I am a very beginner in macro development (and programming in general!). 
Right now I wanted to test a basic loop function for processing images in several directories, and I get an error at the very beginning of the code: 
Statement cannot begin with "{" in line 42. 
I have noted in the code below which line the error shows, apologies if the code is far too long.

I took out the print function. I carefully looked at the spaces etc, but I used an example template from online so it shouldn't be any problem there. 
I couldn't find a similar problem on this or any other forum.

```
FileName = getString("Enter the name of the 2-channel file in each folder", "RGB")
InputFileExt = getString("Enter the file extension", ".tif")
MainDir = getDirectory("Choose the Main Directory");

function processFolder(MainDir) {
    dir = getFileList(MainDir);            
    for (i=0; i < dir.length; i++) {                <---- error 
                print(dir[i] + FileName + InputFileExt)
        if(File.isDirectory(MainDir + dir[i]))
            processFolder("" + MainDir + dir[i]);
        if(endsWith(dir[i] + FileName + InputFileExt) 
            processFile(dir[i] + FileName + InputFileExt);
    }
}

function processFile (dir[i] + FileName + InputFileExt) { 
    run("Split Channels");
    selectWindow("RGB.tif (blue)");
    close();
    selectWindow("RGB.tif (green).tif");
    saveAs("Tiff", MainDir + File.separator + "Split channels" + File.separator + "RGB.tif (green).tif");
    selectWindow("RGB.tif (red)");
    saveAs("Tiff", MainDir + File.separator + "Split channels" + File.separator + "RGB.tif (red).tif");
    close(); 
        }
}
```

This is just to test if the code identifies the correct images and directories. It should go through an RGB image in every single folder, split it in 3 channels, and save the green and red channel in a new folder within the directory where it found the image. 
If there are any other huge obvious mistakes you can spot in the rest of the code, I will be happy to hear them :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have an extra curly bracket at the end of the code, just remove it and the macro should run smoothly.